# Integrating δ(1 - cosθ) over the entire solid angle in spherical coordinates.

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, solid-angle

I don't understand why the following is wrong:
[link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onAix.png)

Should *dθ sinθ* be converted to *-dcosθ*? If yes should *dθ sinθ* be converted to *-dcosθ* for every integral involving *cosθ*?

Comment: Are you saying that the answer $0$, which is derived in the image, is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps I should ask if it is wrong... Is it? And what happens if we replace dθ sinθ with -dcosθ?

Comment: The answer is indeed zero, using that change of variables isn't necessary to see why it is zero.

Comment: It's a small idea to u substitution. The bounds will instead be between $-1$ and $1$

Comment: So do I treat the delta function like any other function taking the difference of the evaluates of the function for the two boundaries? I thought that integrating  the delta function over a range that includes the values for which the nested function becomes zero always yields 1.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $0$. If you want to use $-d \cos(\theta)$ in place of $d\theta \sin \theta$, then you get $$ C \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{-1}^1 \delta_{1-t} dt, $$ which is $0$ if you define $\delta$ function appropriately.